# SymLoadModuleEx returning ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: c++, dll, dbghelp

I'm using `SymLoadModuleEx` from `Dbghelp.h` shipped with VS2015. The function works only once and is returning `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` for next calls. When I change call order so it's called for another DLL (totally different, even located elsewhere) it works once and returns `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` for others.

This mean it's not a problem of loaded DLL because it doesn't work no matter the first DLL.

Its initialized like:

```
SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_UNDNAME | SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES);
SymInitialize(CurrentProcessHandle = GetCurrentProcess(), nullptr, true);
```

And is called like:

```
SymLoadModuleEx(CurrentProcessHandle, nullptr, DllName.c_str(), nullptr, dwBaseAddr, 0, nullptr, 0);
```

DllName is correct and dwBaseAddr is 0.

According to [MSDN SymLoadModuleEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681353(v=vs.85).aspx) everything should work just fine.

Comment: Do you call `SymGetModuleInfo64` after `SymLoadModuleEx` as remarks on MSDN page suggest?

Comment: I did try it but according to documentation it is needed only when deferred loading is enabled which isn't in my case.
Anyway even with `SymGetModuleInfo64` it isn't working.

Comment: The snippets are not very helpful, they don't show the actual code that misbehaves. The universal bug is not using GetLastError() correctly.  It must only ever be called if the function failed.  Getting this wrong produces a random number, it is only 0 by accident.  The snippet has no way to check the function return value, so the real code is pretty likely to go wrong this way.